# Keras, multi-layer autoencoder, the same accuracy for different amount of hidden layers

Tags: keras

I'm currently trying to implement a multi-layer autoencoder using Keras, but I'm starting to believe that my implementation is wrong, since I don't get any difference in accuracy nor variance by using 2 or 3 hidden layers. I tried using two hidden layers with 400/180 and then I tried using three hidden layers with nodes of 400/180/30 and I practically get the exact same result. My code is currently looking like this:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, initializers
import numpy as np
from Dataset import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import time

#global variables
d = Dataset()
num_features = d.X_train.shape[1]
#input = [784, 400, 100, 10, 100, 400]
#output = [400, 100, 10, 100, 400, 784]
#names = ['hidden1', 'hidden2', 'hidden3', 'hidden4', 'hidden5', 'hidden6']

list_of_nodes = [784, 400, 180]

def generate_hidden_nodes(list_of_nodes):
    input = []
    for j in range(len(list_of_nodes)):
        input.append(list_of_nodes[j])
    for i in range(len(list_of_nodes)-2):
        input.append(list_of_nodes[-2-i])
    output = input[::-1]
    return input, output

input,output = generate_hidden_nodes(list_of_nodes)





def autoencoder(epochs):
    w = initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None)
    model = Sequential()
    input, output = generate_hidden_nodes(list_of_nodes)
    for j in range(len(input)):
        if j == (len(input)-1):
            model.add(Dense(output[j], activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=w, input_dim=input[j]))
            #model.add(Dropout(0.45))
        else:
            model.add(Dense(output[j], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=w, input_dim=input[j],
                            ))
            #model.add(Dropout(0.45))
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    history = model.fit(d.X_train, d.X_train,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        batch_size=50,
                        shuffle=True,
                        validation_split = 0.2)
                        #validation_data=(d.X_test, d.X_test))
    #print(history.history.keys())
    #plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
    #print(history.history['val_acc'])
    plt.show()
    return model

def cv():
    accuracy = 0
    size = 5
    epochs = 20
    variance = 0
    storage = np.zeros((size, epochs))
    for j in range(size):
        ae = autoencoder(epochs)
        #print(ae.history.history['val_acc'])
        storage[j] = ae.history.history['val_acc']
    for i in range(size):
        accuracy += storage[i][-1]
    mean = accuracy/size
    for k in range(size):
        variance += ((storage[k][-1] - mean)**2)
    variance = variance/size
    return mean, variance

mean, variance = cv()
print(mean)
print(variance)
time.sleep(10)

def finding_index():
    elements, index = np.unique(d.Y_test, return_index=True)
    return elements, index

def plotting():
    ae = autoencoder(20)
    elements, index = finding_index()
    y_proba = ae.predict(d.X_test)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
    # size = 20
    for i in range(len(index)):
        ax = plt.subplot(2, len(index), i + 1)
        plt.imshow(d.X_test[index[i]].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

        ax = plt.subplot(2, len(index), i + 1 + len(index))
        plt.imshow(y_proba[index[i]].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.show()


plotting()
```

I was expecting a significant difference by sending it down to only 30 nodes in the end (and the decoding it back). Is there an obvious mistake in my code, the dataset I'm currently using is the Mnist dataset (handwritten digits). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without going into detail, why *shouldn't* handwritten digits be compressible to 30 dimensions (which is much larger than 30 bits) ? As we know the invariants (all the numbers are centered, similar thickness), I can imagine that pictures of a single digit (say, zeroes) can be reasonably be compressed in something like 5 dimensions (vertical spread, horizontal spread, angle, size/place of a gap if any). perhaps a few more for extra features, a few more for specifying which digit to draw. IMHO 30 dimensions should still give near-lossless compression. Try using to 5 or 10 dimensions to check.

Comment: I understand what you mean, can you provide me a bit of information concerning the fact that I first reduce it to 180 dimensions and then reduce it to let's say 30 dimensions instead of just reducing it immediately to 30 dimensions, what's the difference, is it better to generalize it like this?

Comment: Autoencoder is not a classifier (at least not without tricks), so I'm not sure what you did there. The accuracy is meaningless.

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean that it is a classifier, what I'm trying to do is to recover my x from the sparse representation of the hidden layer, the accuracy is how well it does recover it

Comment: Let me expand on @Ian reply which I think is the right one. A classifier uses a loss like 'binary_crossentropy'; this means that is trying to predict one of the classes. For an auto-encoder you need to be measure a loss such as 'mean_squared_error'. i.e. the error of reconstructing the image given the lower dimension representation in the "thinner" layer. So if your question is: "is there an obvious mistake" then Ian's comment is correct: the first obvious mistake is the loss function which doesn't make sense here.

Comment: I can actually get a decent result (87 %), with only 1 node at the middle of the hourglass? Can this really be right?